# Initial value dropdownlist Knockout

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author, htmlAttributes:
                    new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select data-bind="options: book.authors,
                       optionsText: function(item) { return item.firstName + ' ' +  item.lastName; },
                       value: book.author"></select>

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author, "",
                        new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>
```

View model is defined as follows:

```
function BookFormViewModel(bookviewmodel) {
    var self = this;
    self.saveCompleted = ko.observable(false);
    self.sending = ko.observable(false);
    self.isCreating = bookviewmodel.id == 0;
    self.book = {
        id: bookviewmodel.id,
        title: ko.observable(bookviewmodel.title),
        isbn: ko.observable(bookviewmodel.isbn),
        description: ko.observable(bookviewmodel.description),
        synopsis: ko.observable(bookviewmodel.synopsis),
        imageurl: ko.observable(bookviewmodel.imageurl),
        authors: ko.observable(bookviewmodel.authors),
        author: ko.observable(bookviewmodel.author)
    };
.....
}
```

The view model is built from a C# class as follows in the .cshtml file

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval", "/Scripts/ViewModels/BookFormViewModel.js")
    <script>
        var viewModel = new BookFormViewModel(@Html.HtmlConvertToJson(Model));
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    </script>
}
```

It is a dropdownlist where I am able to set the Author for each book I have by choosing from a list of existing authors. Setting of a new author works. The only problem I have is that when I show the book the dropdownlist points always to the first author independent of what author is saved in the Book object. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Make sure that, in the object you pass to `BookFormViewModel` as the `bookviewmodel` argument, the `bookviewmodel.author` is really contained in `bookviewmodel.authors`. If it's an object (and not just a string) it must be the **same object instance**. It's not enough if it's just an object holding the same data. Also, I suspect `book.author` needn't be a `ko.observable`. 
And a sidenote: doing `self = this` and using `self` further on doesn't do anything useful. You might as well just use `this`.

Comment: What does `book.author` have? Is that the full author object or just author's id? Since you have omitted `optionsValue`, I'm assuming it has the full object.

Comment: book.author has the full author object

Comment: following on from @adiga, I would suggest finding the equivalent author from the list of authors and assign the self.book.author property the value of the found author.  Just so the object references match.

Comment: Get the author object from `bookviewmodel.authors` which has the same `id` as the current book's authror (`id` or any other unique identifier). Something like `var author = bookviewmodel.authors.find(a => a.id === bookviewmodel.author.id)` and then inside `self.book = { author: ko.observable(author), ..rest of the properties }`

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the following solution:

```
<select data-bind="options: book.authorsids,
        optionsText: function(item) { 
        var auth = book.authors()[book.authorsids().indexOf(item)];
        return auth.firstName + ' ' + auth.lastName;
        },
        value: book.authorid">
</select>
```

where the id is an int. So I decided to use simple data types and not full objects inside the select.